# How can i remove the effect from graph

Tags: php, javascript, graph

I am doing a site in php which has a graphical presentation. I have used amchart graph . I have drawn the graph but when i am using line graph it's loading has some effect, i have to remove that effect. I have added the line graph in fiddle.Please check it.Any help will be appreciated.

> http://jsfiddle.net/soumyamohanan/Qr7we/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr7we/3/),

`chart.startDuration = 0;`